# Can't join dialogs on QuickBlox

Tags: javascript, quickblox

since yesterday (21/01/2016) our group chats aren't working because we get no response after calling the QB.chat.muc.join(dialogJid) method. We also see that automatic "presence" messages don't get any responses either.

The users login and connect to the chat (QB.chat.connect()) without any problem, but the join method suddenly stopped working without us having made any changes.

You can test this issue with this code (we have tested it on v1.16.1 and v2.0.3 of the SDK):

```
var CONFIG = {  
    chatProtocol: {
        active: 2 // set 1 to use BOSH, set 2 to use WebSockets (default)
    },
    debug: {mode: 1} // set DEBUG mode
};

var CREDENTIALS = {
  appId: 34012,
  authKey: 'pwSCOResb4R2Lka',
  authSecret: 'E4sztXGxw5Qk8md'
};

QB.init(CREDENTIALS.appId, CREDENTIALS.authKey, CREDENTIALS.authSecret, CONFIG);

QB.createSession(function(e, r){
    var params = {login: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678'};
    QB.login(params, function(e,r){
        if(r) {                        
            QB.chat.connect({userId: r.id, password: '12345678'}, function(e,roster){
                if(!e){
                    QB.chat.muc.join("34012_56a15ec7a0eb4791ae0003cc@muc.chat.quickblox.com",function(r){console.log(r);});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this is are the console logs:

```
[AuthProxy] createSession Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ServiceProxy] Request:  POST Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ServiceProxy] Response:  Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [AuthProxy] login Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ServiceProxy] Request:  POST Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ServiceProxy] Response:  Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ChatProxy] connect Object
quickblox.min.js:4 [ChatProxy] Status.CONNECTING
quickblox.min.js:4 [ChatProxy] Chat Protocol - WebSocket
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <open xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-framing" to=​"chat.quickblox.com" version=​"1.0">​</open>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <open xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-framing" from=​"chat.quickblox.com" id=​"d6f813bc-ab9f-46c6-92af-059843b73d3d" version=​"1.0" xml:lang=​"en">​</open>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream=​"http:​/​/​etherx.jabber.org/​streams">​…​</stream:features>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <auth xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-sasl" mechanism=​"PLAIN">​ODU2MjA0MC0zNDAxMkBjaGF0LnF1aWNrYmxveC5jb20AODU2MjA0MC0zNDAxMgAxMjM0NTY3OA==​</auth>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <success xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-sasl">​</success>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <open xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-framing" to=​"chat.quickblox.com" version=​"1.0">​</open>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <open xmlns=​"urn:​ietf:​params:​xml:​ns:​xmpp-framing" from=​"chat.quickblox.com" id=​"d6f813bc-ab9f-46c6-92af-059843b73d3d" version=​"1.0" xml:lang=​"en">​</open>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream=​"http:​/​/​etherx.jabber.org/​streams">​…​</stream:features>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <iq type=​"set" id=​"_bind_auth_2" xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" id=​"_bind_auth_2" type=​"result" to=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <iq type=​"set" id=​"_session_auth_2" xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" id=​"_session_auth_2" type=​"result" to=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672">​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [ChatProxy] Status.CONNECTED at 12:14:40
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <iq from=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672" type=​"set" id=​"1:​enableCarbons" xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" id=​"1:​enableCarbons" type=​"result" to=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672">​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <iq from=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672" type=​"get" id=​"2:​getRoster" xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] RECV: <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" id=​"2:​getRoster" type=​"result" to=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672">​…​</iq>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <presence xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​</presence>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <presence from=​"8562040-34012@chat.quickblox.com/​1220770403-quickblox-49672" to=​"34012_56a15ec7a0eb4791ae0003cc@muc.chat.quickblox.com/​8562040" id=​"3:​join" xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​…​</presence>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <presence xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​</presence>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <presence xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​</presence>​
quickblox.min.js:4 [QBChat] SENT: <presence xmlns=​"jabber:​client">​</presence>
```

We haven't been able to do any further development so we would really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much. All my best.

Comment: I see the same behavior, but its a new account so I thought I'm doing something wrong. The callback from join never fires.

Comment: Did you try the account owner user? For me, that is the only user that can join any chat.

Comment: Quickblox already solved this issue. Apparently they had a problem on their servers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just performed a new test by creating a test app on a co-developer's account and on that account everything is working well, so the problem seems to be with my developer's account.

I checked if maybe there was some mistake that caused a massive API calls avalanche but I see in the stats page that the amount of my app's API calls count is very low. So, I don't know what caused this blocking on my account.

Comment: Quickblox already solved this issue. Apparently they had a problem on their servers

Comment: Hey can you please described step by step how you create setup.